# Trying to get peak points labels on my matplotlib plot / underlying data for the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get the peaks value labels for a time series model.  Since I'm a super noobie at Python, looking for some help.

I can run the following code and get a plot, but I'm trying to add value labels at the peaks.  It seems like it should be simple, but after searching for hours I can't figure it out.

```
pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps=100)
pred_ci = pred_uc.conf_int()
ax = y.plot(label='observed', figsize=(14, 7))
pred_uc.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='Forecast')
ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
            pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
            pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.25)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Furniture Sales')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'label' it? Do you mean axis labels, labels on specific data points, labels for lines, or something else entirely?

Comment: labels on the data points specifically

Comment: *All* data points? Or just ones that satisfy a certain condition (i.e. each peak)?

Comment: Sorry, each peak

Comment: Please be more clear on what you're asking to help people help you =) Look for `annotations` in `pyplot` that will lead you in the right direction.